# I can't add new customer in the Magento 2.4 frontend

Tags: customer

I am having the following problem: I cannot add new clients from the store frontend (Magento 2.4.) I have already verified the existence of $ block-> getBlockHtml ('formkey') in the form, I have already changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 (I am testing locally) and when I submit the form nothing happens, it does not show any error or create adds the new client.
In the backend I can add new customer without any problems

I have cleaned, flushed the chache and reindexed.

Please does anyone have any ideas about what I'm missing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does the cookie domain match your base_url?
Check both web/cookie/cookie_domain and web/secure/base_url in db table core_config_data.

HTH, Tom

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tom. The web/cookie/cookie_domain field had a null value so I made it match with base_url but nothing happened, I still can't add clients. After this change in the database cleaned the cache and reindexed all files.